# Using LINQ, what are the ways to get the top x rows of a navigation property?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a navigation property, say Items, of an object, say Order.  If I want to get a list of Orders, including the Items, I can do something like:

```
var orders = dbContext.Order.Include(o => i.Items);
```

This works great, but now I'd like to get only 3 items for each order and I am wondering the best way to accomplish this.

One way is to perform the following:

```
var orders = 
    (from o in dbContext.Order
     join i in dbContext.Items on o.Id equals i.OrderId
     select new { o.Id, i })
    .GroupBy(o => o.Id)
    .SelectMany(i => i.Take(3))
```

This works well, although the generated SQL is is bit complex, but I am wondering if there is a more direct (or performant) way.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: This is difficult to do (and usually not very efficient) in SQL as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var orders = dbContext.Order
    .Select(o => new
    {
        Order = o,
        Items = o.Items.Take(3)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(a => a.Order)
    .ToList();
```

This will fill the `Order.Items` collection with the top 3 items automatically if

- you don't disable change tracking (not the case in the query above)
- the relationship between `Order` and `Item` is not many-to-many (probably not the case because orders and items usually have a one-to-many relationship)

**Edit**

The generated SQL query is:

```sql
SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
FROM (SELECT 
      [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
      [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id1], 
      [Limit1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
      CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
      FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
      OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (3) 
          [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
          [Extent2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
          FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent2]
          WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[OrderId] ) AS [Limit1]
) AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Wont this generate a bunch of SQL statemnents (3 per order)? (In Linq-to-SQL it will at-least)

Comment: @Magnus: No, it's one single SQL query.

Comment: With `OUTER APPLY` to sub query?

Comment: @Magnus: I don't know how the SQL looks exactly. I will do a test in a few hours, extract the SQL and post it into my answer. Will notify you here...

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, there is an `OUTER APPLY`, see Edit section above.

Comment: Thanks for the update, very interesting. Linq2SQL was not able to produce a single SQL statement with that linq query. Perhaps its finally time to give entity framework a chance. I've evaluated entity framework in the past, but it always produces really crappy SQL compared to linq2SQL on fairly complex queries.

Answer (score 3):

How bad is the performance?  If it's tolerable then I'd leave it alone.  There's not a straight-forward way to do this in SQL either.  Usually you end up with a sub-query that computes the `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned by your grouping, then returning rows where the row number is less than `n`.

Since there's not a direct translation of that mechanism to Linq, I'd keep the Linq understandable and not worry about the complexity of the generated SQL unless it's a SIGNIFICANT performance problem.

You could also compare it to the performance of returning ALL items then filtering using Linq-to-Objects.

Another option would be to code this as a stored procedure instead of trying to do it in Linq.

Answer (score 3):

This should generate simple SQL in the form of an `OUTER APPLY` with top 3 statement to Items. We then have to do some grouping using linq-to-objects, but only the data we need have been brought from the server.

```
var orders = 
   (from o in dbContext.Order
    from i in (from x in dbContext.Items
               where o.Id == x.OrderId
               select x).Take(3).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Order = o,
        Item = i
    }).AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(x => x.Order)
      .Select(x => new { Order = x.Key, Items = x.Select (y => y.Item ) });
```

And if you only want the top 3 items per order without the order entity. Will generate `CROSS APPLY` with top statement in SQL to items.

```
var items = 
      from o in dbContext.Order
      from i in (from x in dbContext.Items
                 where o.Id == x.OrderId
                 select x).Take(3)
      select i;
```